# How can I centre an object whose height I do not know in a list?

Tags: html, css

It seems like no matter what I do I just can't get some text with a black background to centre vertically. The problem is that sometimes the text is on one line and sometimes it is on two or even three. I'm trying to get it to automatically adjust but I just can't.

I have tried numerous approaches such as those listed on [here.](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Here is my code I am trying to centre:

```css
.infogrid {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 45px;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0px 1% -100% 1%;
  width: 98%;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
.infogrid ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.infogrid li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  width: 320px;
  margin: 1vw;
  height: 320px;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  box-shadow: 0.2vh 0vh 0.8vh #888888;
}
.infogrid li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
}
.tilewrappertext {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", "Arial", "Sans-Serif";
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.75;
  font-size: 2.2em;
}
#tilewrapper:hover .tilewrappertext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="infogrid">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div id="tilewrapper">
        <img id="automargins" src="content/tile1.png" width="96%">
        <h3 class="tilewrappertext">Half price facials</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="tilewrapper">
        <img id="automargins" src="content/tile2.png" width="96%">
        <h3 class="tilewrappertext">1/4 off massages</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="tilewrapper">
        <img id="automargins" src="content/tile3.png" width="96%">
        <h3 class="tilewrappertext">20/3 off hot rocks</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="tilewrapper">
        <img id="automargins" src="content/tile4.png" width="96%">
        <h3 class="tilewrappertext">20/3 off nails</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="tilewrapper">
        <img id="automargins" src="content/tile5.png" width="96%">
        <h3 class="tilewrappertext">Free use of sauna with treatment</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="tilewrapper">
        <img id="automargins" src="content/tile6.png" width="96%">
        <h3 class="tilewrappertext">Free use of jacuzzi with treatment</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="tilewrapper">
        <img id="automargins" src="content/tile7.png" width="96%">
        <h3 class="tilewrappertext">1/20 off eyes</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div id="tilewrapper">
        <img id="automargins" src="content/tile8.png" width="96%">
        <h3 class="tilewrappertext">1/20 off hair</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The text appears when the image is hovered over.

Comment: Only one HTML element should have a given id value. All of your div and img elements use the same id.

Comment: In other words, what @ScottMarcus trying to say, use `class` instead of `id`. `id` is for unique elements and cause problems if not unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your li is already position relative, you can add the following css rules to the h3 to center it vertically within the li.:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
margin: 0;
```

Example here: http://codepen.io/nicerhugs/details/dMGMEv/

The top will move the top of the h3 halfway down the li, and the transform will correct for the height of the li itself. Getting rid of the margin will take away that weird mystery space that makes it appear to be lower than it really is.

Answer (score 0):

Just go with the Jess's answer. Here is another method to do this using `pseudo element` aka `ghost element` in `css`.

You have to give `absolute` position to image. add a `:after` element to `div#tilewrapper` and make it display `inline-block`, also make the `h3` tag `inline-block` and apply `vertical-align: middle`, it will position vertically middle. Little complicate to understand but anyway Here is the code . :)

```css
.infogrid {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 45px;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0px 1% -100% 1%;
  width: 98%;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
.infogrid ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.infogrid li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  width: 320px;
  margin: 1vw;
  height: 320px;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  box-shadow: 0.2vh 0vh 0.8vh #888888;
}
.infogrid li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
}
.tilewrappertext {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", "Arial", "Sans-Serif";
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.75;
  font-size: 2.2em;
}
#tilewrapper:hover .tilewrappertext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.infogrid{
  margin-top: 50px;
}
img {
    max-height: 320px;
    position: absolute;
}

div#tilewrapper{
    height: 100%;
}

.tilewrappertext {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", "Arial", "Sans-Serif";
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.75;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: calc(100% - 4px);
}

div#tilewrapper:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="infogrid">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div id="tilewrapper">
        <img id="automargins" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-fqGa-MyjVHY/UZPYekbmfHI/AAAAAAAABrg/CC4q0AQsY9o/s320/air-baloon.jpg" width="96%">
        <h3 class="tilewrappertext">Half price facials</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
   
  </ul>
</div>
```